# golang custom struct undefined, can't import correctly

Tags: go

I've got 2 sibling files: main and test_two. In each is the file main.go and test_two.go respectively. In one I've got a custom struct and in the other I want to run a function with that struct as a param. I'm getting the error "undefined: Struct".

```
package main

import "github.com/user/test_two"

type Struct struct {
    Fn    string
    Ln    string
    Email string
}

func main() {
    foo := new(Struct)
    foo.Fn = "foo"
    foo.Ln = "bar"
    foo.Email = "foo@bar.com"
    test_two.Fn(foo)
```

test_two.go:

```
package test_two

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Fn(arg *Struct) {
    fmt.Println(arg.Fn)
}
```

Comment: You should define `Struct` in test_two since that's what you import in your main file. Basically the `test_two` doesn't know about what's inside the `main` package.

Comment: If the files are siblings in the same directory, they need to be in the same package.

Comment: @JimB - they're in 2 different packages. the folders are siblings

Comment: @this.lau_ - I'm hoping to have multiple places calling func Fn() so I was hoping to have the struct defined elsewhere, and the passed to Fn(). Is that not good practice?

Comment: Then you should define this struct in a third package, that way you can import from any other package.

Comment: @this.lau_ I'll keep that in mind. For the example shown tho, is this causing my problem? I can't figure out why this wouldn't be working...

Comment: @jj1111: how would your example work? `*Struct` isn't defined in package `test_two`

Comment: @JimB when I try to import it I get "import cycle not allowed". I've tried changing test_two to be: func Fn(arg *main.Struct)

Comment: @jj1111: which is why you either need to define it in `test_two` where it could be imported by `main`, or you have it in a separate package.

Comment: @JimB - ok I'm with you now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some rules to live by:

- Don't define types in main (usually)
- Don't try to import main in other packages
- Don't try to import both ways (import cycle)
- Always import from a lower level into a higher one (so mypkg into main)
- All folders are packages, put related data/functions in them and name them well

You probably want something like this:

```
app/main.go
app/mypkg/mypkg.go
```

with contents for main.go:

```
// Package main is your app entry point in main.go
package main

import (
    "stackoverflow/packages/mypkg"
)

func main() {
    foo := mypkg.Struct{
        Fn:    "foo",
        Ln:    "foo",
        Email: "foo@bar.com",
    }
    mypkg.Fn(foo)
}
```

Contents for mypkg.go:

```
package mypkg

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Struct struct {
    Fn    string
    Ln    string
    Email string
}

func Fn(s Struct) {
    fmt.Printf("func called with %v\n", s)
}
```